# convergence of Taylor series on R

Tags: real-analysis

I am doing this problem: Let $f\in C^{\infty}(R,R)$ be an infinitely differentiable function on R. Assume that there exist constants $C>0$ and $\rho>0$ so that for any integer $n\ge 0$, $$|f^{(n)}(x)|\le Cn!/\rho^n.$$ Prove that for any $x\in(-\rho,\rho)$, $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n.$$ Is this true that the above equality also holds for all $x\in R$? If your answer is NO find a counterexample.

I think I can do the first part, since $$|\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n|\le\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{Cn!}{\rho^nn!}|x^n|=\sum_{n=0}^{k}C(\frac{|x|}{\rho})^n,$$
and $\frac{|x|}{\rho}<1$.

But I don't know how to do the second part. I think it is not true. Is there any counterexample?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor's Theorem says
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k+\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}x^n
$$
for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$. For $|x|\lt\rho$, we can bound the remainder term by
$$
\left|\,\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}x^n\,\right|\le C\,\left|\,\frac{x}\rho\,\right|^n
$$
which can be made as small as we wish by taking $n$ large.

This series does not necessarily converge to $f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Take for example
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\frac1{1+x^2}\\
&=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8-x^{10}+\dots
\end{align}
$$
The Taylor series converges for $|x|\lt1$, but not for $|x|\gt1$.